# Problem while trying to update style of a Jsx element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ProgressBar extends Component {


  render() { 

      let progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
      let valueContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-value');
      const speed = 20;
      let progressValue = 0;
      let progressEndValue = 70;

      function updateElements() {
        valueContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-value');
        progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
      }

      const createProgress = setInterval(() => {
        progressValue++;
        updateElements();
        valueContainer.innerText = `${progressValue} %`
        progressContainer.style.background = `conic-gradient(
            rgb(239 68 68) ${progressValue * 3.6}deg,
            black 1deg,
            rgb(241 245 249) 1deg,
        )`
        
        if (progressValue == progressEndValue) {
            clearInterval(createProgress);
        }
    }, speed) 

    return (
      <div className='progress progress-container w-full h-full rounded-full flex justify-center items-center'>
        <div className="progress w-3/4 h-3/4 rounded-full bg-slate-100 flex justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className='progress-value' >0 %</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}


export default ProgressBar;
```

So here is my code, I am basically trying to create a dynamic animated circular progress bar here.
I use updateElements function to prevent the uncaught error of null, the progress value is changing between 0 and 70 percent successfully in the DOM. but the conic-gradient background does not applying in the DOM from the function. but if I set it statically in the CSS file with the same code. it works.

**Someone help me please I am struggling since yesterday!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class ProgressBar extends Component {
    state={
        progressValue:0,
        speed:20,
        progressEndValue:70
    }

  render() { 

      let progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
      let valueContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-value');

      function helperFunctions() {
        valueContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-value');
        progressContainer = document.querySelector('.progress-container');
        
      }

      const createProgress = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.state.progressValue <= this.state.progressEndValue) {
            this.setState({progressValue:this.state.progressValue+1});
            helperFunctions();
            valueContainer.innerText = `${this.state.progressValue} %`
            progressContainer.style.background = `conic-gradient(rgb(239 68 68) ${this.state.progressValue * 3.6}deg,black 1deg,rgb(241 245 249) 1deg)`        
     
        } else {
            clearInterval(createProgress);
        }
        
    }, this.state.speed) 

    return (
      <div className='progress progress-container w-full h-full rounded-full flex justify-center items-center'>
        <div className="progress w-3/4 h-3/4 rounded-full bg-slate-100 flex justify-center items-center">
            <h1 className='progress-value' >0 %</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
}

export default ProgressBar;
```

Now it works fine :)

suggestion:

If your were using functional component, it could be done much easier and you could use useRef intead of document.querySelector as it is recomanded is React document

**The main problem was the last , in conic-gradient**